# PHP and Javascript Get borough from google maps using Streets

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a set of incomplete addresses which only have streets and house numbers only. And I was wondering is it possible to pass that incomplete address in the google maps API and get a full address (with borough).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the best practices when geocoding addresses published in the official Google documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

As you can see Google suggests using [Place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) web service in case of incomplete and ambiguous addresses.

> Use the Places API Place Autocomplete service when geocoding ambiguous (incomplete) addresses or for latency-sensitive applications, like when responding to user input.
>
> **Automated system processing ambiguous queries:** Ambiguous queries are those that contain poorly formatted addresses, incomplete addresses, or spelling mistakes. For automated systems, we recommend using the Geocoding API web service. However, the Geocoding API is not designed to cope with ambiguous queries and may produce less accurate results or zero results in response to ambiguous queries. If your automated system processes a high rate of ambiguous queries that are derived from user input, you may benefit from adding an interactive element to your app using the Place Autocomplete service in the Places API, since it is designed to return multiple possible options and to allow a user to choose between them.

I hope this helps!